# Jboss 7.1.1 Final occuping huge physical RAM of linux

Tags: jboss7.x, hornetq, java-6

I am using jboss 7.1.1 Final with jdk version 1.6.0_45 and while starting jboss i just configured 5gb for heap and 1gb for non-heap. My Linux complete RAM size is around 60GB. After starting jboss some time i can see from linux top command its occupied ram is 50GB. Moreover from jconsole & jvisualvm tool i can see my jboss ram utilization keep up & down reaching max 90% ( approx. using between 4-5 gb)

```
top - 11:52:35 up 1 day, 17:40,  4 users,  load average: 0.89, 1.20, 1.27
Tasks: 174 total,   1 running, 173 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 12.1%us,  1.8%sy,  0.0%ni, 85.8%id,  0.0%wa,  0.1%hi,  0.2%si,  0.0%st
Mem:    62.948G total,   49.872G used,   13.076G free,  347.309M buffers
Swap: 8197.219M total,    0.000k used, 8197.219M free, 2053.590M cached
```

And Jboss parameters are like this :

```
-D[Standalone] -server -Xms5120m -Xmx5120m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:PermSize=1024m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+UseParNewGC
```

Please help out why more Linux RAM is consumed ????

Regards
Veera

Comment: First I would suggest not to use version 7.1.1, which is buggy. There's a 7.1.3 that contains over 600 fixes. It is not downloadable, you have to build it yourself.

Comment: Are you sure that your JBoss process is consuming this amount of memory ? How many threads are running in the process ? And is your application consuming only heap memory, or "off heap" memory as well ?

Comment: thanks for you reply @Alexis. From monitoring tool i can see the threads information. Live threads : 218, Daemon Threads:115, Peak Thread Count : 252 and Total Threads Started :18818. But from monitoring heap and non-heap utilization showing are normal 1-90% in between. But i am not sure how to prove that who is consuming 49GB.

Comment: thanks for suggesting to go with 7.1.3 . parallelly i will start building that.

Comment: Be careful with the non-heap memory. You probably monitor only perm space. Stack and other blocks are non-heap as well. For example, some cache engines use off-heap memory.

Comment: Thanks Alexis once again for you suggestion.